# How Can we achieve Masonry like design in .NET MAUI CollectionView or List view(Or any other Display Collections)

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, maui

I am trying to show list of items in .NET MAUI but my figma design contains Masonry design with 2 columns(only) similar to below image:
[image]

How Can we achieve Masonry like design in .NET MAUI CollectionView or List view(Or any other Display Collections) for android and iOS?

I have tried with below approach using placeholer api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoSamples}" Grid.Row="1" 
    IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">

<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalItemSpacing="5" Span="2" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PhotoSample">
        <ContentView Padding="5">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" Aspect="Center"
                WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" Margin="0,0,0,10" />

                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

but it results in gaps when height is different as shown in below emulator screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What about the grid layout?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/?view=net-maui-8.0#grid

Comment: Hi @jason.kaisersmith it won't work as I have updated my question in more details.

Comment: Alternate name to search on: [Lazy Staggered Grid](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-staggered-grid)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the Masonry layout by combining grid and verticalstacklayouts. Basically you will place inside a Grid a VerticalStackLayout for each column.

[image]

Here is a code snippet:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
            Padding="0"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="Start">

            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                <Image Margin="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    HeightRequest="100"/>

                <Image Margin="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                    HeightRequest="50"/>

                <Image Margin="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Bisque"
                    HeightRequest="70"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                <Image Margin="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    BackgroundColor="BlueViolet"
                    HeightRequest="100"/>

                <Image Margin="5"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Brown"
                    HeightRequest="80"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

The result will be the below output.

[image]

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**

You can create the above view by code, that will speed up the rendering process. The below code renders the items of your list in 2 columns. Both columns are scroll together, no extra care needed. The view is very fast, give it a try.

full code can be found here:
https://github.com/imoulas/sample-maui-net-expense-app

```
public class MasonryPage : ContentPage
{
        public MasonryPage()
        {
            BindingContext = new MasonryViewModel();
            MasonryViewModel viewModel = (MasonryViewModel)BindingContext;

            Grid grid = new()
            {
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition(),
                    new ColumnDefinition()
                }
            };

            VerticalStackLayout stackLayout1 = new();
            VerticalStackLayout stackLayout2 = new();

            ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();

            int split = viewModel.Items.Count / 2;
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (ItemImageModel model in viewModel.Items)
            {
                StackLayout stack = new()
                    {   BackgroundColor = (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString( model.Color )),
                        HeightRequest = model.LayoutHeight,
                        Margin = 5
                    };

                if (counter < split) {
                    stackLayout1.Add(stack);
                }
                else
                {
                    stackLayout2.Add(stack);
                }
                counter++;
            }

            grid.Add(stackLayout1, 1);
            grid.Add(stackLayout2, 0);

            ScrollView scrollView = new()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(20),
                Content = grid
            };

            Title = "Masonry demo";
            Content = scrollView;

        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @isidoros-moulas, Thank you. I tries this approach and the issue with this approach is when long list is present, I can scroll left column and right column separately. This provides a very bad experience.

Comment: @AjayVerma i tested the above and the scroll goes to both columns at the same time. I suppose you try the above with a binded collection view inside the verticalstacklayout and that will cause the scrolling. May be it's worth trying to create the specific page without XAML, so the generated page will have all controls pre-rendeded. If this not works for you, a workaroung is to detect the scroll event of the 1st collectionview, and apply the position to the 2nd collectionview. Let me know how you implemented this.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update when I found my solution.

Comment: Hi @Isidors Moulas, Thank you for your reply. I tried with your approach and for this I have divided my main dataLiat (within View Model) into two parts(based on even/odd index) for first row and second row. 
The issue is  it takes lots of time to update UI(view) and make app unresponsive.

Comment: You mean you tried to create the UI by code? If yes and it is taking time may be is worth trying to add the elements on the background (meaning on another thread). That will cause the page to be shown (empty) until the background thread finishes (an activity control will inform the user for this loading period).

Comment: Hi @Isidoros, I am following this approach: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshop-mobile-client
When I ReloadData on ObservableCollection, it take too much time(35-40sec to 1 min) with evenodd photo library.

Comment: So, you have two observable collections or just once? And at xaml you have one collection view or two? The proposed idea is two have two observable collections one for each column.

Comment: yes, I have two observables collections but as soon as I divide data set into two parts, it take lots of time to load.

Comment: The loading items process (reload) should be into a separate thread. Afterwards you will notice that the items are shown into the page as soon they added (instant), and you will have the feeling that loading is completed as the view will gradually showing the new images.   I haven’t check the sample, but I assume that now all items are displayed together as the loading process finish which is the reason why it’s taking so long. Also note that loading huge images will also cause a delay. For resolving the size issue you have to create small preview images and show them into the new view.

Comment: Yes this is happening exactly like you mentioned. Do you have a sample/example on how I can proceed?

Comment: Generally you need Task.Run async. Check this sample https://github.com/imoulas/sample-maui-net-expense-app/blob/master/ViewModels/ExpenseViewModel.cs It’s much simplier than the one you followed.

Comment: Hi @Isidoros I'll try and update with your solution and finding.

Comment: Hi @AjayVerma, I have made a small sample for the masonry view. Have a look the updated answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want a staggered layout [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0) for viewing items with different heights(2 columns) and this is a feature request [Staggered Layout for CollectionView #9659](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9659) that has been raised on Github. You can follow up there.

The aim is to add the property `StaggeredLayoutItems` as `ItemsLayout` option for the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0):

```
public class StaggeredItemsLayout : ItemsLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty Span;
    public int _span { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @AjayVerma No worries, you can also refer to [Implement StaggeredLayout #7761](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7761), Javier has provided a sample: [Beautyshop App](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/netmaui-beautyshop-app-challenge) that uses custom control.

Comment: Hi @Alexandar, Thank you but I tried with 100 set of records and it is not working properly. It is only suitable for very small set of data. So it won't fit for my scenario.

Comment: @AjayVerma Yes, you can use that Custom Layout is if the number of records is not very large.